# Apigee Monitoring API for 500 errors

Tags: apigee

I am trying to call the monitoring API of api to get back stats on my api's to determine the error counts. However, i only want to see 5XX errors and not 4XX.

I tried the api below based on the documentation listed below however, doest seem to work. Any suggestions?

https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{env}/environments/test/stats/apis?select=error_count&timeRange=11/14/2014%2000:00~11/25/2014%2000:00&timeUnit=minute&filter=(responsecode EQ 500)

**Documentation:**

http://apigee.com/docs/analytics-services/reference/analytics-reference

Comment: What is the error you see? Can you first try without the filter and then try the filter just to make sure that the API is working and it is not a data issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and I get a 500 error with the response

```
{
    "contexts": []
}
```

Looks like a bug.